# Не удается установить phpmyadmin на Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Пишу:

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
```

Получаю следующий ответ:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   
> Building dependency tree
>   
> Reading state information... Done
>   
> E: Unable to locate package phpmyadmin
>   
> E: Unable to locate package php-mbstring
>   
> E: Unable to locate package php-gettext

Пытался применить команду:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
```

Но безуспешно.

Как справиться с этой ошибкой?

Comment: списки пакетов-то получили перед тем как пытаться устанавливать что-нибудь из этих списков? `$ sudo apt update`

Comment: Да, разумеется.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/666587/178576

Answer (score 0):

> Пытался применить команду:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin

А зачем там --remove ? Вы же хотите добавить репозиторий?

Comment: "...нельзя выполнить обновление безопасным способом"

Comment: phpmyadmin в ubuntu должен быть в дефолтных репозиториях. попробуйте удалить все сторонние репозитории,  обновить списки и посмотреть есть ли нужный пакет в списке: ` sudo apt update && sudo apt search phpmyadmin`. Если не поможет скиньте выхлоп комманд: ` cat /etc/apt/sources.list` и `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`